# Spoiler Tagging for videos

Tags: feature-request, spoilers, videos

I am coming to you from SFF.SE. Videos are a large resource to us for asking and answering questions. Our community is also known to be *particular* when it comes to spoiler alerts...

I recently [tried to post answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133943/57310) (to a Game of Thrones question) with video confirmation of a large spoiler.

A workaround was used to by just linking the video instead of embedding it.

However, as seen in the same answer, we can apply spoiler tags to pictures.

**My request is to be able apply spoiler tags to embedded videos.**

Comment: So these video embeds autoplay now?

Comment: @random No, but they may include spoiling titles on display, or a spoilerish screenshot.

Comment: I just ran into this issue. It'd be great to be able to hide embedded videos in spoiler tags.